# dynamically change the functionality based on incrementing the i value

Tags: android, xml, dynamic

I am currently working on Android

I have a xml which is like this:

```
<Point pointid =1> // first point tag
  <a>
</Point>
<Point pointid =4> // second point tag
 <a>
</Point>
```

I am fetching the pointid attribute from XML with this code:

```
NodeList listOfPersonsi = doc.getElementsByTagName("Point");
String p = ((Element)listOfPersonsi.item(i)).getAttribute("pointid");
```

here **i** value will be 0 for first point and 1 for second point.

I have a button called next when i click on that button I am incrementing the i value, but I want something like this if the `pointid  = 1` I have to perform some action and if `pointid = 4` i need to perform different action.

so

```
if(i == 0) // i value may be 1,2...etc
    {
       if(pointid == 1)
       { 
            "one functionality "

        }else if(pointid == 4)
        {
            " another functionality"
         } 
     }
```

but I want to acheive this dynamically I dont want to hardcode it as 1 and 4 to perform some action

Please help

Comment: Let me counter by asking you this: if you didn't know how p == 1, how would you know what functionality to carry out? Is the functionality tied to a particular value of p?

Comment: hi Nick thanks..sorry thats not p its pointid i will edit it now...

Comment: @NickCampion i am able to fetch the value of pointid but when i value is 0 or 1 etc it should check for pointid value if it returns 1 then one action or if it returns 4 other action but it should be dynamic...

Comment: Nick Campion is right. Unless the action to be taken is can somehow be derived from the value pointid you will need to hard code each case. I would use a switch statement though for readability

Comment: @Goofy sorry, I don't understand. "but it should be dynamic" is confusing, making a decision based on the value of pointid sounds like "dynamic" to me.

Comment: @NickCampion i mean to say i dont want to hardcode the values as 1 and  4 i want it to be dynamically acheived ...please help i am stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `List<Integer> pointIds` and as you parse the xml, call `pointIds.add(pointId)` as you find additional ids. Then modify your code to see if later `pointId.equals(pointIds.get(0))`. This entire mechanism seems pointless. I'm having trouble deducing why you need this to be "dynamic".

Comment: the reason for dynamic is i may have different functionality for each point in the xml. thanks i will try and get back to you on this.